# How to completely uninstall symfony and composer from a mac

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I want to completely remove symfony and composer from my mac. I have been googling for five hours and no documentation can be found on how to uninstall composer and symfony completely from my mac. Why is that so hard to find? even on the Symfony website.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Symfony on your computer is just a folder containing the framework and the structure of the files, so you can delete that folder and you are done. Composer is just an binary file (phar) that can run on the command line. Locate where that file is and delete it.

Comment: I tried to look for composer but I don't see it in it's location

Comment: @Ed: `composer` should have local cache in your user folder (`.composer` directory)

Answer (score 9):

Symfony could be anywhere on your mac.

The 'installer' for mac that comes from here https://symfony.com/download (dd 2019/10) dumps symfony in your home directory in ~/.symfony . I dislike that, too.

```
ls -al ~/.symfony
```

if it's there,

```
rm -rf ~/.symfony
```

That 'installer' suggests you may want to move it here

```
ls -al /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

if it's there

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above answer to

```
rm -rf ~/.symfony
```

but you do not need to run ls to check beforehand, if it's there, it is going to be deleted. If not, it is being ignored.

Better do

```
whereis symfony
```

to check where your binary is and delete it.

Last but not least check if you have installed it via apt, this is a valid solution:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d  && ls | grep symfony-cli
sudo rm symfony-cli.list && sudo apt update
```

This will avoid checking for updates on every apt update