# PHP Symfony server - "An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver"

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, driver

I start my Symfony application named "test2" using the terminal command `symfony serve` (I also tried `symfony server:start`), and I get an error:

> Exception thrown when handling an exception
> (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: An exception occurred in
> driver: could not find driver at
> /var/www/html/test2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php
> line 102)

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, PHP 7.4, Symfony CLI 4.25, and in case needed, Composer 2.0

I'm also using PostgreSQL, and I ran `sudo apt-get install php-pgsql`.

I checked "php.ini" as well, here's a screenshot:
[image]

This is the entire response that highlights the error(s):

```
[Web Server ] May 31 09:01:32 |DEBUG  | PHP    Using PHP version 7.4.18 (from default version in $PATH)
[Application] May 30 23:09:16 |CRITICA| REQUES Exception thrown when handling an exception (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver at /var/www/html/test2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 102)
[Application] May 30 23:09:16 |CRITICA| PHP    Uncaught Exception: An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
[Application] May 30 23:16:58 |INFO   | REQUES Matched route "index". method="GET" request_uri="https://localhost:8000/" route="index" route_parameters={"_controller":"App\\Controller\\TestController::index","_route":"index"}
[Application] May 30 23:16:58 |INFO   | SECURI Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
[Application] May 30 23:16:58 |CRITICA| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver" at /var/www/html/test2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 102
[Application] May 30 23:16:58 |CRITICA| REQUES Exception thrown when handling an exception (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver at /var/www/html/test2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 102)
[Application] May 30 23:16:58 |CRITICA| PHP    Uncaught Exception: An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
[Application] May 30 23:16:58 |CRITICA| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver" at /var/www/html/test2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 102
[Application] May 30 23:16:58 |CRITICA| REQUES Exception thrown when handling an exception (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver at /var/www/html/test2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 102)
[Application] May 30 23:16:58 |CRITICA| PHP    Uncaught Exception: An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
[Web Server ] May 31 09:01:32 |INFO   | PHP    listening path="/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4" php="7.4.18" port=45197
[PHP-FPM    ] May 31 09:01:32 |NOTICE | FPM    fpm is running, pid 391
[PHP-FPM    ] May 31 09:01:32 |NOTICE | FPM    ready to handle connections
[PHP-FPM    ] May 31 09:01:32 |NOTICE | FPM    systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance to any helpers :)

Comment: did you check your php.ini to see if the extension=pdo_pgsql is uncommented

Comment: Yes, pretty sure it's uncommented. I just added a screenshot of "php.ini". Thanks for asking.

Comment: It is not in use in the above screenshot, remove the leading `;` from that line and restart you webserver and/or php-fpm

Comment: try to remove the semi colon at the begining and se if it work

Comment: Tried it, then restarted "sudo service apache2 restart", but unfortunately, still the same problem :(

Comment: Have you checked the correct php.ini file? Can you include the output of `symfony local:php:list`? Given that you are using ubuntu try `sudo phpenmod pgsql pdo_pgsql`, you *should* have that command installed.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but ignore all the nonsense about restarting the server.  'symfony server:start' uses php's built in server.  As mentioned before, 'symfony local:php:list' will tell you if you have multiple php versions installed.  And 'symfony php -m | grep pgsql' will verify if the pdo_pgsql extension is actually loaded.

Comment: I did in fact have 2 PHP versions, now I only have one. Sadly, it didn't work. But when I entered `symfony php -m | grep pgsql`, there was no error but nothing happened. Is that normal?

Comment: It means that the extension is not loaded. Double check all your `php.ini` files or try `phpenmod` again, it's part of the `php-common` package.

Comment: I checked all php.ini files. And when I type "phpenmod", here is the response: `WARNING:
usage: phpenmod [ -v ALL|php_version ] [ -s ALL|sapi_name ] module_name [ module_name_2 ]`

Comment: @zach See my previous comment, the full command to execute is `phpenmod pgsql pdo_pgsql`, that would enable the module for all SAPIs and versions.

Comment: I tried it, still unable to find the driver. Could I be in the wrong directory? ("/var/www/html/test2" since the Symfony app is called "test2"). I also tried ".../test2/public" since "index.php" is in that folder, but it returns "Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql'")

Comment: Solved the problem! Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! I removed and reinstalled PHP's PostgreSQL extension, anything linked to Symfony, and permanently removed unused PHP versions. I also surprisingly left the comments in "php.ini", didn't need to touch it. It now works.

Here's a link that explains how to remove Symfony (look at the 2nd answer with `ls -al ~/.symfony`, etc.): [How to completely uninstall symfony and composer from a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356581/how-to-completely-uninstall-symfony-and-composer-from-a-mac)

To remove PHP's PostgreSQL extension: `sudo apt-get --purge remove php-pgsql` or `sudo apt-get purge php-pgsql`

And I removed unused PHP versions on my system: `sudo apt-get purge 'php5.6'`

To reinstall PHP's PostgreSQL extension, I entered `sudo apt-get install php-pgsql`

And to get Symfony again, I followed its steps here: https://symfony.com/download (for Linux)

Thanks to everyone who offered their help. I greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to remove the semicolon from that line and then restart your webserver.

Usually something like `sudo service httpd restart`.

Comment: I tried it, did "sudo service apache2 restart" (tried "httpd" as well, but said it didn't exist), and I still have the same problem :(

Comment: Do you know what web server you are running / os?