# /usr/local/bin/symfony: 2: /usr/local/bin/symfony: Syntax error: newline unexpected

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu-18.04

I am going to create project with symfony 5.3

I am just running the command

> `symfony check:requirements`

Then I am getting the following error.

```
/usr/local/bin/symfony: 2: /usr/local/bin/symfony: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

Is this a symfony installer error?

Comment: What OS do you use? What PHP version? Did you update Symfony (the binary, not the project) recently?

Comment: Hi, i am using ubuntu 18.04 with php 7.2

Comment: Currently I am using symfony 3.4 and now I am shifting to 5.3

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding comments. And please be aware that PHP 7.2 is End of Life. Not sure, but this might be the reason it doesn't work; Symfony doesn't support if anymore. See https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: And add some information about what you've tried to fix this problem. I found similar problems when I searched the error message.

Comment: I have move to php 7.4 and re-installed the symfony installer. Then problem was solved..

Comment: PHP 7.2 is out of all support plans since Jan 2021. Please consider changing to any supported version of PHP, along with any supported version of Symfony (as Symfony 3.4, which you've mentioned in the comments, is also near the end of all kinds of support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the  symfony and php version conflict.

Uninstall the Symfony and Re-installed it.

Uninstall Symfony :

> [How to completely uninstall symfony and composer from a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356581/how-to-completely-uninstall-symfony-and-composer-from-a-mac)

Re-install symfony:

> https://symfony.com/download